# Is a write to variable on a single core CPU atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I have a single core CPU ([ARM Cortex M3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Cortex-M3), 32bit) with two threads. Assuming the following situation:

```
// Thread 1:
int16_t a = 1;
double b = 1.0;
// Do some other fancy stuff including starting Thread 2
for (;;) {std::cout << a << "," <<b;}

// Thread 2:
a = 2;
b = 2.0;
```

I can handle the following outputs:

- 1,1
- 1,2
- 2,1
- 2,2

Can I be certain that the output will always be one of those (1/2) without using `mutex` or other locking mechanisms? And more specifically, is this compiler dependent? And is the behavior different for `int16` and `double`?

Comment: Use `std::atomic<double>` for _atomic_ access.

Comment: Your code has, completely portably and independent of compiler, *undefined behaviour*. All implementations are perfectly equally free to do whatever they want.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ. Unfortunately I don't have access to it due to compiler restrictions (e.g. no C++11). But otherwise this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the CPU, mostly, though in theory anything involving multiple threads on pre-C11 is at best implementation defined and at worst undefined behavior, so the compiler might do just about anything.

If you can ignore crazy compilers that do silly things, and assume that the compiler will use the CPU's facilities in a reasonable way, it depends mostly on what the CPU supports.

Cortex-M3 is a 32-bit CPU with a 32-bit bus and no FPU.  So reads and writes of 32-bit and smaller values will generally be atomic.  `double`, however, is 64 bits, so any read/write of a double will involve two instructions and be non-atomic.  Thus if one thread reads while the other is writing you might get half from one value and half from the other.

Now in your specific example, the values 1.0 and 2.0 are both 0 for their lower half, so the 'mix' would be innocuous, but other values will not have that behavior.

Comment: I'm confused now. In case I would stick to two 32bit ints or lower the writing is atomic? (Not guarantied by any standard but in practice)

Comment: In practice, yes 32-bit and smaller ints will be atomic.  Of course, any accesses to mulitple variables might be reordered unless you stick (compiler specific) barriers between them.

Comment: I always thought that the 32bit was a reference to the memorize address size. Meaning that 2^32 bits can be addressed. Does this also pose a lower limit of addressable memory size block?

Comment: "32bit" just means that some things in the CPU are 32 bits wide.  Other things are other sizes.  To figure out what, you need to look at the instruction set and CPU specification.  ARM6 has 8, 16, and 32 bit load/store instructions.  There are also LDM/STM instructions that can load and store multiple registers in one go, but they mostly just used for frame save/restore situations.

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation order of the operations before the ; are not guaranteed left to right, even if it were, they are not atomic, you will get a segfault if you try and read and write to a at the same time (they can & do take multiple cycles to perform and a context switch can interrupt it).

On arm in particular reads and writes go in a queue on the cpu where they are free to be reordered (except past memory barriers), even on a cpu that doesn't reorder memory the compiler is also free to reorder them. There is nothing stopping your assignment and read being moved forward or back and so you cannot guarantee the state of any of the values or ordering.